# Hyper V Virtual Swtich Configurations for single physical network adpater

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, virtualization, windows-server-2012, hyper-v

How does HyperV Virtual Machine > Virtual Switches work?

I am installing a Hyper V on Win Server 2012 R2 and it is asking me to select the Network adapter for Virtual Switch. I have only one physical network port on server which is listed as the only option.

However, at just below it, it is displaying a notice that 'We recommend that you reserve one network adapter for remote access to this server. To reserve a network adapter, do not select it for use with a virtual switch.'

That clearly says, I should not select this only network adapter. What should I do?

I am planning to use it to create multiple VMs for testing purposes that will need network access. And I'm not sure how to configure this correctly. Also should I need to add another physical network adapter?

Expert advise needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, at just below it, it is displaying a notice that 'We
>   recommend that you reserve one network adapter for remote access to
>   this server. To reserve a network adapter, do not select it for use
>   with a virtual switch.'
>
> That clearly says, I should not select this only network adapter. What
>   should I do?

Ideally you would have one dedicated NIC to use for connecting to and managing the Hyper-V host and another dedicated NIC from which to create a Hyper-V virtual switch. In your case, you have only one NIC so you have no choice but to use this NIC for both purposes. There's nothing inherently wrong with doing this.

Comment: Noted. That means, if I select this, I will still be able to connect to host machine using this adapter. Right?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Thanks. And with this can I still publish a web service hosted on VM which can be accessed by outside host in a LAN?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 2):

In a production deployment, you would ideally have a management network separate from the network that your virtual machines use. This text refers to setting up such a management network. You can operate Hyper-V without a separate management network, but that traffic will contend with VM traffic.

Comment: If I use the current network adapter, will i will be able to connect to LAN & WAN resources from within VM?

Comment: Um, you would be able to connect to anything the network allows you to connect to.